# Unable to launch WebdriverAgent of xcodebuild failure: xCodebuild failed with code 65

Tags: python, ios, configuration, anaconda, appium

I am a test automation engineer responsible for running automated tests on an iOS application using Appium. However, I've encountered a critical issue when trying to launch WebDriverAgent, a crucial component for iOS automation. The error message received is "Unable to launch  WebdriverAgent of xcodebuild failure: xCodebuild failed with code 65." This error is preventing me from executing my automated tests, and it's imperative to resolve this issue promptly. Appreciate anyone could help on this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weGUV.jpg)

Anyone can help on this issue?

Comment: You need to properly sign WebDriverAgent and potentially build it successfully on a device at least once before attempting to run it through Appium. Have you followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md) listed in the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.